# Mysql select row with same value column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a student mark table with 4 question answers marked as 1,-1, and 0 means correct, incorrect, and not attended respectively. I am adding a table structure below. What I am looking for a MySQL query to update another column as selected or not selected based on how much 1 they got. So if my condition is a student which got at least 1 got will select then I can write
`UPDATE table SET selected = 1 WHERE total_mark > 0` (atleast one correct will get a mark of greater than 0).

No, I need at least 2 selected or 3 selected how will I write an update query.

[image]

Comment: Redesign your schema; a database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want at least 2 `1`s for the column `selected` to be `1`, then:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET selected = (m1 = 1) + (m2 = 1) + (m3 = 1) + (m4 = 1) >= 2
```

Each of the boolean expressions `mx = 1` evaluates to `1` or `0` for `true` or `false`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=66ee0fa9fc0f9070b0c4e3f316a7e5ef).
Results:

```
> id | name  | m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | selected
> -: | :---- | -: | -: | -: | -: | -------:
>  1 | user1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |        1
>  2 | user2 |  1 | -1 | -1 | -1 |        0
>  3 | user3 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |        1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to improve your relational model, by creating a USER_ANSWERS table, then you can simply count the answers having score = 1. Then you are not dependant of the number of questions you have in a survey.

If its not something you want to do, this query does the trick :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET selected = 1 WHERE GREATEST(0,m1) + GREATEST(0,m2) + GREATEST(0,m3) + GREATEST(0,m4) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but its showing Invalid use of group function

Comment: @Jasir : you are right, SUM is not useful here ( my relational habits :D ), see the edit.